# Mac OS X Lion full-screen event

Tags: cocoa, macos, fullscreen, osx-lion

Is there an event to let the application know when it enters full-screen mode in Lion? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? It's there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications don’t enter full-screen mode, windows do. Try [NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and its brethren.